# Declaring arrays in VBA, option explicit

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, declaration

I'm new to Excel applications with VBA.

I've been told to declare all the variables throughout my code, by using the "Option Explicit" statement.

In the code below (which is only a small part of the actual program), I'm trying to read the contents of the range C4:L6 and assigns those to the variable "Bar":

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
Sub My_PROGRAM()
Dim Bar() As Long
Bar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:L6").Value 'Reads the contents of the range
End Sub
```

I keep getting a Run-Time error '13' - type mismatch.

My question is, how do I declare a 2D array? I tried Dim Bar(1 to 3, 1 to 10) but that didn't work either.

If I don't use Option explicit, the program works just fine

```
Option Base 1
Sub My_PROGRAM()
Bar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:L6").Value 'Reads the contents of the range
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `Dim Bar() as Variant`

Comment: Arrays read in from Excel ranges are arrays of variants.  However, the  best way to declare a variable for receiving an array from excel is 'Dim Bar As Variant' because a variant can hold an array. 'Dim bar() as Variant' is declaring an Array of Variants.